# Adding a data member to eigen matrix class

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I want to use Eigen3 as backend engine for a simple real-time audio processing library. The key idea is to pass Eigen-exressions through a chain of fully templated processors, with each processor returning a modified eigen-expression. It would be very useful, if these expressions could carry a timestamp or other reasonable meta-data along.

For example, I'd like to be able to do the following: Given

```
Signal X(3, 1);
X << 1 , 0 , 0;
X.start_time = 0;

Signal Y(3, 1);
Y << 2 , 0 , 0;
Y.start_time = 2;

Signal Z(5, 1);
Z << 1, 0, 2, 0, 0;
Z.start_time = 0;
```

then the following expressions shuold evaluate to `true`

```
(Z == X + Y).all();
(X+Y).start_time == 0;
```

I've tried to extend the Eigen::Array class: I'm using a plugin 
as described [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_Plugins.html) to add the data member in the ArrayBase class, and i've defined a subclass with the appropriate constructore and assignment operator as described in the [documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_InheritingMatrix.html). Setting / getting the data member directly works fine. (See example below)

However, when I construct an expression and assign it to another Signal, the member is not copied. This is actually clear as I the construction of the expression does not involve the Signal constructor but some constructors higher in the class hierarchy. 
As far as I see, i can't implement a custom constructor / assignment op in the plugin, as they are already defined in the respective vanilla class.

```
// ./eigen_extension.h

int my_member; // plugin to declare my_member in the eigen base class.


// main.cpp
#define EIGEN_DENSEBASE_PLUGIN "./eigen_extension.h"
#include <Eigen/Dense>


class Signal : public Eigen::ArrayXXf
{
    using Base = Eigen::ArrayXXf;

public:

    Signal(): Base()
    {
        this->my_member = 0;
    }

    template <typename OtherDerived>
    Signal(const Eigen::ArrayBase<OtherDerived>& other)
        : Base(other)
    {
        std::cout << "cpy ctor my_member: " << this->my_member << ", other: " << other.my_member << std::endl;
        this->my_member = other.my_member;
    }

    template <typename OtherDerived>
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE
    Signal& operator=(const Eigen::ArrayBase<OtherDerived>& other)
    {
        this->Base::operator=(other);
        std::cout << "cpy ass my_member: " << this->my_member << ", other: " << other.my_member << std::endl;
        this->my_member = other.my_member;

        return *this;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Signal X;
    X.my_member = 5;

    std::cout << X.my_member << std::endl; // prints 5

    auto Y = X * X;  // invokes copy ctor, prints cpy ctor my_member: -858993460, other: -858993460
    //Signal Y(X);

    std::cout << Y.my_member << std::endl; // prints -858993460, should print 5.
}
```

I've also tried some variations of the above code, including making the constructor / assignemnt operator using universal references or placing the plugin to different levels of the eigen class-hierarchy.

My question is, whether and how it would be possible to get my scenario working.

Comment: `EIGEN_DENSEBASE_PLUGIN` is intended for extending the API (i.e., adding additional methods) not adding the ABI. I don't understand what you actually want to achieve here. E.g., if you have an expression tree, you will have multiple `my_member` variables (one in the root of each (sub-) tree). If you know what you are doing, you can just work on a copy of the Eigen library and modify the constructor as you want to.

Comment: To clarify my question: What do you expect `Z.my_member` to be in case of: `Signal X, Y; X.my_member = 1; Y.my_member=2; auto Z = X*Y;`?

Comment: Thanks @chtz for your comments. The idea is to be able to align two signals according to their timestamps (or channels)  in order to improve decoupling of the single processors. I've edited the question to include an example usecase. I was afraid that it will require hacking the eigen codebase but I hoped that someone would know a better way to do it. Perhaps I'll prefer object composition here.